# TextField makes a new line when done is pressed rather than dismissing keyboard Xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm learning Xcode and Swift, so I decided to go through the tutorial on the Apple Developer website. I've set up my text field to dismiss 
the keyboard as the tutorial said, but rather than dismissing the 
keyboard and performing the action done by

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
```

the text field just makes a new line and the keyboard doesn't dismiss.

Before typing and pressing done:

[image: Image of Iphone 7 Simulator before typing and pressing return]

After typing and pressing enter:

[image: Image of Iphone 7 Simulator after typing and pressing return]

Here is my code:

[image: My code]

Comment: Oh my god it is. So dumb!! Thank you so much

Comment: That is the behaviour of a UITextView

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var textField : UITextField

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.textField.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: It's still making a new line every time I press return, not activating textFieldShouldReturn

Comment: have you add this line: self.textField.delegate = self

Comment: it seems you are using UITextView not UITextField

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that it is a UITextField and not a UITextView

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , UITextFieldDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldTXT: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        textFieldTXT.delegate = self
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textFieldTXT.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

}
```